# Closing Coronavirus questions

Tags: discussion

I'd like a debate about how we should treat Coronavirus related questions. Right now there are no open questions tagged [Coronavirus](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coronavirus) or [COVID-19](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) on ux.stackexchange.com. I posted one, and that was closed.

Given that our current involvement in the subject matter is zero (0), should we evaluate whether our effort on the subject is appropriate? I would suggest that, given the gravity of the issue, that we start treating all incoming contributions as well intended, and rather than closing, that we try to improve the questions and answers so that we in the end arrive at findings that can possibly be shared with the wider community.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a User Experience question that somehow relates to Coronavirus then it'll be allowed. If it's not a UX question, or is not specific enough to UX to fall within scope then it'll be closed off.

We're not a medical Stackexchange site afterall. We're a UX one. If people want advice on the virus then there are sites out there with actual experts on epidemiology. We're not that site. And in fact I'd say it's dangerous for us to be answering such questions here. Because we don't know what we're taking about. Just because it's an important topic doesn't mean it's suitable for here.

Comment: Well said, there couldn't be many Corona related UX question since it hardly bring up any new changes to the UX, maybe an information panel or some notice text.